# DecimalFormat on setText

Tags: java

I'm working on a JFrameForm, just remaking some old exercises on a GUI. I was wondering if I could use decimal format on a `setText();` This is my code:

```
private void btn_calcularActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  DecimalFormat redondear=new DecimalFormat("##.##");

  double radio;
  double area;

  radio=Double.parseDouble(txt_field_radio.getText());

  area=Math.PI*Math.pow(radio, 2);

  txt_field_area.setText(Double.toString(area));
```

This is the line I'm curious about: `txt_field_area.setText(Double.toString(area));`. If I put 2 as radius I want it to output 12.56; instead it outputs 12.566370614359172.

I tried this:

```
txt_field_area.setText(redondear.format(Double.toString(area)));
```

But it outputs an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number
```

Answer (score 1):

Look this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00##");
String result = df.format(34.4959);
```

You need call redondear format method

```
private void btn_calcularActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    DecimalFormat redondear=new DecimalFormat("0.00##");
    //******* VARIABLES *****
    double radio;
    double area;
    //****** CAPTURA DE DATOS ****
    radio=Double.parseDouble(txt_field_radio.getText());
    //****** OPERACIONES *********
    area=Math.PI*Math.pow(radio, 2);
    //**** IMPRESION ***********
    txt_field_area.setText(redondear.format(Double.toString(area)));
```

Comment: I already tried that yesterday BUT I get an error: https://gyazo.com/8783958c494657214fa60fec85d4cb8e

Comment: These errors should not be made in DecimalFormat (), rather, it is a series of errors related to your project

Comment: oh, do you know how I could find this problem?

Comment: Podemos hablar por Twitter y quizas pueda ayudarte

Comment: Yo hablo español ;-)

Comment: sure, I just followed you!

Comment: Send me a message to locate you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166418/discussion-between-hector-manuel-martinez-duran-and-jeremy).